# Similar code but doesn't work

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print("%s%s" % (" "*i, "*"*(n-i))
```

This code works well. And this is the output.

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I want to change it upside down.
So I tried like that.

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print("%s%s" % (" "*i, "*"*(n-i))
```

But it doesn't work and even is not compiled.

Comment: I forgot something important.
There was more code
 : n = int(input())

Comment: You're missing an extra closing paren: `print("%s%s" % (" "*i, "*"*(n-i)))`

Comment: COLDSPEED
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `)`:

```
print("%s%s" % (" "*i, "*"*(n-i)))
```

You got three `(` but only 2 `)`. Adding the last one should work. [Try it here!](https://repl.it/Jo62/9)

Example output:

```
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```